# xrandr not showing my VGA port, instead it lists DP1

Tags: 16.04, vga, displayport

OS Ubuntu 16.04
Videocard Intel HD graphics 530 Skylake GT2

When I run `xrandr` the following is displayed.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

It shows *eDP1* which is my built in display, *HDMI1* which is my additional monitor *VIRTUAL1* and *DP1* which I can't identify.  The problem is that my laptop doesn't have a displayport.  It has a VGA port which is not listed.

How can I get *xrandr* to recognize my vga port and where is this mystery *DP1*?

Comment: Maybe the ports are simply mislabelled. What happens when you try to connect a display to the VGA port? Does it show up in the display settings of Ubuntu or the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: Nothing changes when I connect to the VGA port

Answer (score 1):

Your hardware actually doesn't support *native* VGA output.
See: http://www.anandtech.com/show/9483/intel-skylake-review-6700k-6600k-ddr4-ddr3-ipc-6th-generation/4

This means that the VGA you see and use, is an adapter, an internal adapter.
This could explain why *xrandr* reports DP1 instead VGA1

Comment: Nothing changes when I attach a monitor to the VGA port.  Is there a way to check and see if the port is actually connected to the video card without taking the laptop apart?

Comment: (We are going a little bit out of topic). Anyway, maybe is it disabled from the BIOS?

Comment: I don't know how to check its status in regards to the BIOS.  If anyone has time to explain it I have a rather basic understanding of linux operations and terms (Introduction to linux course I took a while ago).

Comment: BIOS it's not a linux issue. For further info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS  . Anyway, once you enter in the BIOS setup (it depends on your own PC model, often you need to press CANC or F12 or F5 or F2...), you have to look for a setting regarding video outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to force the output through DP1, as done in this answer.

[VGA not listed in xrandr: Intel Kabylake Graphics, No output on projector](https://askubuntu.com/q/966883)

As others have pointed out, it might have been just mis labelled port.

Also, try other fixes in the same question which might help.