# Ubuntu 16.04 not detecting external HDMI monitor

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics

Yesterday, I installed all the latest Ubuntu updates on my System 76 laptop with intel graphics, and I think one of them has caused my problem. I have tried the steps here: 
[HDMI stops working when DisplayPort is unplugged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968883/hdmi-stops-working-when-displayport-is-unplugged/970436#970436)

and they fail:

```
$ sudo lshw -C video 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   3200x1800     59.70 +
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93* 
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
$ 
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as eDP-1
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
$
```

I have power cycled the laptop and the monitor, still no luck.  I updated the intel-video drivers:

```
 intel-graphics-update-tool
```

I think this is related to the intel-microcode update I did yesterday but I am not sure how to back it out (or if I should).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `xrandr` with the external monitor connected? Thanks.

Comment: The output in the comment is with the external monitor connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annoyingly, I stumbled to the solution while trying to fix the problem.  I run gnome3 on this machine, and in and attempt to fix the problem with this:

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel xorg-video-abi-20 xserver-xorg-core`

and it removed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and many `xorg` drivers... so when I rebooted, the keyboard and mouse did not work. I booted into a live CD, mounted and `chroot` to the main partition and removed `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and reinstalled `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and all the `xorg` drivers came along with it.

When I rebooted, back to the main partition, I had return functionality to the keyboard and mouse and the external monitor worked too.