# I need to re-connect HDMI everytime after boot

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi

I'm using a lenovo yoga, with ubuntu 20 and a usb-c to hdmi converter.
I'm also using a secondary screen. However, the hdmi connection never works on boot. I'll have to unplug the hdmi cable, and re-insert it for it to work again.

Can I do something for the laptop to automatically find this hdmi connection on boot?
Would love your input on this issue.

The lenovo uses Intel UHD Graphics 620.

Comment: Is this helpfull? https://askubuntu.com/questions/968883/hdmi-stops-working-when-displayport-is-unplugged  it is not exactly your question.

Comment: Append the question with the output of `xrandr` before USB reconnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently tried another adapter, where my problem does not appear. I tried out the tips from the answers but only another adapter solved the problem.

Comment: There is also the option of USB-C monitors, eliminate the adapter altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I would comment but I can't, sorry. I had a very similar problem a few years ago on ubuntu 16.04. I had to unplug the hdmi cable and plugin again every time I turned on the laptop. I was using NVIDIA driver and I have accidentally discovered that when I switched to Nouveau driver the problem disappeared. Later on with an upgrade the problem was fixed for the Nvidia driver as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are similar problems reported [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/XMG_gg/comments/f21v4k/bug_monitor_plugged_in_with_usbcdisplayport_is/):

- Bug: Monitor plugged in with USB-C/DisplayPort is not connected on boot (have to manually replug)

The description of the problem:

> I am using the USB-C to DP adapter provided by XMG and BIOS version
> 0060.
>
> Every time I boot or restart my Fusion 15, my monitor plugged in with
> USB-C is not connected. It stays off, and does not show in Display
> Settings. My HDMI monitor starts fine.
>
> Only when i unplug & re-plug the USB-c cable, the screen turns on and
> is connected like it's supposed to.

Of the many comments the most relevant:

> So they fixed it in 0056; broke it in 0060; fixed it again in 0062,
> and now broke it again in 0064? What are they doing over at Intel???
>
> Funny because that's one of the things specifically mentioned in the
> 0064 changelog:
> https://www.reddit.com/r/XMG_gg/comments/ea8vtn/xmg_fusion_15_drivers_firmware_bios_updates/
>
> Thanks for the heads up, I hadn't updated yet. I suggest you downgrade
> to 0062 if you want to fix it. Tagging /u/XMG_gg

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth while having a look at your UEFI configuration. Controlling how external devices are attached is possible with Dell laptops.